# What are the names of these plants?

Tags: species-identification, botany, plant-anatomy

I found these plants in my backyard in South Florida. What are they?[image: plant 1]

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. Remove one of the species from the post and open a new question for it. Additionally, we ask that more details be provided for species ID including size of specimens and more accurate locaiton (Florida has various habitats, so it'll be useful to others in the future to know where you saw these plants). Please add more details.

Comment: failure to follow my previous advice will likely result in your question becoming closed and going unanswered. Please put a bit more effort into your post(s) to avoid this scenario. We want to help, but we need you to cooperate too. Thanks!

Comment: I just figured out how to edit it. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main plant in the photo (with the larger leaves) is called Virginia creeper. The botanical name is Parthenocissus quinquefolia.   The leaves are very distinctive in leaf groups of 5 to 7 leaflets.  It is an aggressive woodland vine in the grape family Vitaceae.

Links:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenocissus_quinquefolia

https://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=paqu2